# Blender distorting objects when using move tool

Tags: objects, transforms

When I try to move any object it either gets distorted or the centre point of the object moves. Has anyone experienced this before?

[image: Screenshot of problem]

Here is the link to the blender file
[2]: [image]

Comment: sorry, this download link no longer exists :(

Comment: link doesn't work

Comment: Hi and welcome to Blender Stackexchange. Please use [blend-exchange](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) to upload .blend files. Files on other services tend to "vanish", thus rendering your question and possible answers practically useless in the future.

Comment: Hey Metaphor, sorry I didn't know. I have reuploaded the file. If any of you could please take a look I would greatly appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have *Affect Only* > *Origins* enabled in your *Viewport Options*. On some it just moves the origin point but maybe on others with modifiers that work in relation to the origin it can distort objects. Disable it.

[image: origins only]

Comment: This worked, thanks so much! I'd upvote if I could :)

Comment: You're welcome. You might consider accepting this answer, read here: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)